ESLint not working with JSX or JS files but works fine with TS and TSX files
Had this similar issue when using Prettier. I'm on macOS and the only project I had so far in VS Code used exclusively TypeScript and no JSX files at all. When I switched to a project where we are using JSX, ESLint doesn't work.
If I create a TSX file in that same project it works fine. It seems that somewhere JSX is disabled for ESLint. I checked my settings.json (that's where Prettier had JSX disabled) but I don't know where else to look. I've tried all the solutions I could find. Nothing seems to work. Could maybe completely removing ESLint fix this issue? Or reinstalling VS Code? I tried using:
"eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "javascriptreact", "html", "typescriptreact" ],

that still did not work. My settings.json is:
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 0.4,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": null,
  "eslint.validate": [
    { "language": "javascript", "autoFix": true },
    { "language": "typescript", "autoFix": true }
  ],
  "eslint.format.enable": true
}

Linting in console works but nothing shows up in VS Code to indicate that there is any issues in my code.
console_screenshot
vscode_screenshot
